# Error when downloading node sass version 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-sass

when running

```
npm install --saveDev node-sass@4.5.3
```

I am getting this error I have tried many things like removing node modules and package-lock.json and installing window-builder-tools and also installing Cygwin but nothing seems to work please help although version 8 is working I think I need 4 because of some error that requires version 4 thanks in advance

```js
    npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade 
asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
npm ERR! Build started 6/25/2022 3:39:36 AM.
npm ERR! Project "C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" on node 1 (default targets).npm ERR! ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
npm ERR!   Building solution configuration "Release|Win32".
npm ERR! MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]
npm ERR! Done Building Project "C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Build FAILED.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! "C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
npm ERR! (_src_\libsass target) ->
npm ERR!   MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     0 Warning(s)
npm ERR!     1 Error(s)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Time Elapsed 00:00:02.67
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Acer\\Downloads\\Frndsmeet\\client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | ia32
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python27\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.EXE -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.14.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.14.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing Visual Studio C++ core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing a Windows SDK (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.* or Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Some required components are missing, not using this installation
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing Visual Studio C++ core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing a Windows SDK (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.* or Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Some required components are missing, not using this installation
npm ERR! gyp verb Not using VS2017: No usable installation of VS2017 found
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:9544) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypinpm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypinpm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Acer\\Downloads\\Frndsmeet\\client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',        
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Acer\\Downloads\\Frndsmeet\\client\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',     
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Acer\\Downloads\\Frndsmeet\\client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Acer\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Acer\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Acer\\Downloads\\Frndsmeet\\client\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\Acer\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Acer\\Downloads\\Frndsmeet\\client\\node_modules\\node-sass',       
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Acer\\Downloads\\Frndsmeet\\client\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
npm ERR! Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
npm ERR! Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
npm ERR! Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture ia32
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\Acer\.node-gyp\16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry 
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Acer\\Downloads\\Frndsmeet\\client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="    
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-25T00_38_11_826Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: it says in the error `To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\Frndsmeet\client\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]`
npm ERR! `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Don't use `node-sass` anymore.

`node-sass` has been deprecated

You can easily fix this by installing the new version `sass`. It will work without any further changes needed.

You can uninstall the old and install the new one

```
npm uninstall node-sass

npm install sass
```

Answer (score 3):

node-sass 4.x will not support Node 16 for the supported versions see https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Answer (score 1):

> To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.

Simply follow the steps above which are listed above & in the error you provided. I encourage you to read the errors more closely.

[.NET 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773)

[Visual studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)

Another possibly helpful thing to download, [Visual C++ build tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126)

## Adding something to the system path on windows 10/8.1

From MATLAB answers, [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94933-how-do-i-edit-my-system-path-in-windows)

1. Right-click on the Start Button
2. Select “System” from the context menu.
3. Click “Advanced system settings”
4. Go to the “Advanced” tab
5. Click “Environment Variables…”
6. Click variable called “Path” and click “Edit…”
7. Click “New”
8. Enter the path to the folder containing the binary you want on your PATH.
9. Click “OK” to save the changes to your variables and restart your computer for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps to fix this issue:

1. Remove dependency of `node-sass` from the `package.json` file
2. Rename the `package-lock.json` file
3. Delete the `node_modules/` folder
4. `npm install`
5. `npm install node-sass`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers but I found changing from node-sass to sass was the best for me